# De-serializing Protoc Generated C# class results in data getting wiped out

Tags: c#, json, json.net, protocol-buffers, proto

when I de-serialize the protoc generated C# object, the property that I have set gets wiped out. Can anyone help? I am using `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package.
Is anything wrong with the proto file("SimplifiedProto.proto" in the test C# solution)?

### The proto file content

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_outer_classname = "SpreadProtos";

option csharp_namespace = "SpreadProtos";

message Parameters {
    oneof instanceOrGroup {
       string Instance = 10;
       string Algo = 60;
    }
}

message Spread {
    Parameters parmeters = 10;
}
 
message Order {
    double minFilledPercentage = 10;
    Parameters parmeters = 30;
}
 
message Request {
    oneof newRequestOpt {
        Spread create = 5;
    }
    string clientRequestId = 100;
}
```

### C# program

```
Request request = new Request()
{
    ClientRequestId = "someId",
    Create = new Spread()
    {
        Parmeters = new Parameters()
        {
            Instance = "someInstanceValue"
        }
    }
};

string jsonConvertStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
Request requestJsonConvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(jsonConvertStr);
//At this point the value stored in Instanc Prop is lost
```

Thanks
J

Comment: To be clear: are you saying that the value isn't round-tripping via JSON.NET correctly? What does the JSON string look like here? (As a side note: this DTO is intended for protobuf; if it doesn't work with JSON.NET: that's probably not a huge design goal)

Comment: Hi Marc, That is correct. I wish I could provide the C# class generated using "protoc.exe" but I couldn't attach it here.. But if you were to generate it using the tool, and set the value as in the code above, serialize it and then de-serialize, "ClientRequestId" is empty.

Comment: are you sure `ClientRequestId` is impacted? that is a property of `Request`. You were previously talking about values under `Instance`, which is a *very* different proposition. I would *expect* `ClientRequestId` to work fine - the generated code is just a backing field and property getter and setter (with a null-check), without any conditional serialization etc

Comment: Sorry i meant "Instance".. once you deserialize, that is gone.. if you are familiar with proto compiler(protoc), you can generate the class a try it yourself. I couldn't attach that class here..

Comment: I'm very familiar - in fact, you can use my tool here to generate the code https://protogen.marcgravell.com/ - just change the drop down to CSharpProtoc to get the protoc version. Personally, I prefer protobuf-net's approach, but I'm biased :)

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, the problem here is that the generated code does not include "conditional serialization", which means it writes both strings as `""` when serializing (rather than omitting the invalid one). You can see this here:

```cs
    /// <summary>Field number for the "Instance" field.</summary>
    public const int InstanceFieldNumber = 10;
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
    public string Instance {
      get { return instanceOrGroupCase_ == InstanceOrGroupOneofCase.Instance ? (string) instanceOrGroup_ : ""; }
      set {
        instanceOrGroup_ = pb::ProtoPreconditions.CheckNotNull(value, "value");
        instanceOrGroupCase_ = InstanceOrGroupOneofCase.Instance;
      }
    }

    /// <summary>Field number for the "Algo" field.</summary>
    public const int AlgoFieldNumber = 60;
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
    public string Algo {
      get { return instanceOrGroupCase_ == InstanceOrGroupOneofCase.Algo ? (string) instanceOrGroup_ : ""; }
      set {
        instanceOrGroup_ = pb::ProtoPreconditions.CheckNotNull(value, "value");
        instanceOrGroupCase_ = InstanceOrGroupOneofCase.Algo;
      }
    }
```

When deserializing, it then writes the string both times, which means: the last one wins, even if it wipes the value.

The good news is: it uses partial classes, so: you can probably fix this!

Try (untested) in a separate file:

```cs
namespace SpreadProtos {
    partial class Parameters {
        public bool ShouldSerializeInstance() =>
            instanceOrGroupCase_ == InstanceOrGroupOneofCase.Instance;
        public bool ShouldSerializeAlgo() =>
            instanceOrGroupCase_ == InstanceOrGroupOneofCase.Algo;
    }
}
```

This `ShouldSerialize*()` pattern is a well-known approach recognised by many serializers, including (IIRC) JSON.NET; the result should be that only the active field gets serialized, which should prevent it breaking things during deserialization.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I am going to try this and get back. I am wondering why an obvious issue like this is not addressed by Protoc.

Comment: @Zest4Quest as I said: protoc is mostly concerned with how *itself* will serialize (to either protobuf or json), not how *external* tools will do it; FWIW, as I also said: protobuf-net gets something a bit more useful